# My HTTPS (SSL/TLS) nginx configuration give me timeout

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, https, certbot

I am trying to configure a HTTPS protocol for my domain https://www.clarinaceramics.com/

In order to do so, I've used certbot and generate a certificate for my server_names. The problem is that I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error every time I try to access my website via https. I think it is a firewall configuration error, but I don't see where.

here is my nginx configuration :

```
server {
  server_name 51.210.109.195 clarinaceramics.com www.clarinaceramics.com;
  root /var/www/com.clarinaceramics/clarinaceramics/client/build;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
     try_files $uri /index.html =404;
   }

   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/clarinaceramics.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/clarinaceramics.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And here is my wfc configuration:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
9813                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
9813 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Do you have any clue ? I've passed 2weeks on this issue without beeing able to resolve it, I'm not a devOps I precise ;)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after somer research, I tested my 443 port, it wasn't open. My ufw was however configured to authorize SSL request.

After diging, I found that OVH provides a firewall in the customer space, that was blocking 443 requests.